# Karma-coverage checks test coverage in JS files instead of TS in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli

I check test coverage in TypeScript files via Istanbul. And I need to set test threshold via karma-coverage.Istanbul's reports don't match karma-coverage reports (I use Angular-cli) because karma-coverage checks test coverage in JavaScript files instead of TypeScript. I used other plugins such as karma-threshold-reporter,istanbul-threshold-checker but result the same. How can I resolve it?

[report generate for typeScript files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hwnB.png)

[report generate for JS files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4xfc.png)

```js
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', 'angular-cli'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-remap-istanbul'),
      require('karma-coverage'),
      require('angular-cli/plugins/karma')
    ],
    files: [
      { pattern: './src/test.ts', watched: false }
    ],
    preprocessors: {
      './src/test.ts': ['angular-cli']
    },
    remapIstanbulReporter: {
      reports: {
        html: 'coverage',
        lcovonly: './coverage/coverage.lcov'
      }
    },
    coverageReporter: {
      dir: 'coverage/',
      reporters: [
        {type: 'text-summary'},
        {type: 'html'}
      ],
      check: {
        global: {
          statements: 70,
          branches: 70,
          functions: 70,
          lines: 50
        }
      }
    },

    angularCli: {
      config: './angular-cli.json',
      environment: 'dev'
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'karma-remap-istanbul', 'coverage'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
plugin: ['karma-remap-istanbul', 'karma-istanbul-threshold'],
  coverageReporter: {
        type: 'in-memory',
    },

    remapCoverageReporter: {
        'text-summary': null,
        json: './coverage/coverage-final.json',
        html: './coverage/html-ts'
    },

    istanbulThresholdReporter: {
        src: './coverage/coverage-final.json',
        reporters: ['text'], 

        thresholds: {
            global: {
                statements: 90,
                branches: 90,
                lines: 90,
                functions: 90,
            }
        },
    },
```

This configuration worked for me.